# Access Version from Xamarin Solution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a multi plattform project in `Xamarin`. The Version Number for each `.csproj` Project (iOS, Android, Mac, Windows) The Version number is set from the `.sln` Solution options.

My problem now is to retrieve the version number from the solution file without having access to the individual Projects.

I know that there are solutions to get the Version number from like `NSBundle` in iOS and similar in other platforms, however I can't use those.

EDIT: This is the structure of my Solution called `ETCS` (git branch develop). There I have a Project `ETCS` which is the core funtions and the Projects `ETCS.***`, one for each platform.

[image: Solution Explorer]

The version number is set in the solution from where the projects get that number. See image below. What I need is a way to set a `constant` in the core function project.

[image: Version number setting in Project]

Comment: I don't know if such a function would be compile time or run time. It doesn't really matter to me, however I believe getting that value from the solution would be at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

A solution (`.sln`) is a plain text file, no xml, json, etc.. so you can parse it however you want.

If you add a version via Visual Studio for Mac/MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio you end up with a `GlobalSection` in the `.sln` of:

```
GlobalSection(MonoDevelopProperties) = preSolution
        description = Sushi's Most Amazing App
        version = 3.14
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Note: The solution `metaproj` produced via `MSBuildEmitSolution=1` does not contain this information, so you can not use built-in MSBuild features to parse it.

Parse the version out (using bash here, but use your own choice to tool(s):

```
export slnVersion=`grep "version =" SomeSolutionFile.sln | cut -f 2 -d "=" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -cd "[:print:]"`
```

Now you have the version (in an env. variable in this example).

If you have a `.cs` file (`Global.Template`) that looks like this:

```
namespace MovieMadness
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public const string SolutionVersion = "SushiHangover";
    }
}
```

You can replace `SushiHangover` with the solution based version:

```
export slnVersion=`grep "version =" SomeSolutionFile.sln | cut -f 2 -d "=" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr -cd "[:print:]"`
sed -e 's/SushiHangover/'"$slnVersion"'/g' Global.template > Global.cs
cat Global.cs
```

Results in:

```
namespace MovieMadness
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public const string SolutionVersion = "3.14";
    }
}
```