# Is there a way I can access the build version of a project in my Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can code this in manually so it appears on an information screen but instead is there any way that I can access the build information such as this:

[image]

Into my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/), it includes a class called [VersionTracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms) that will let you do just that. For example, version and build version can be retrieved like this:

```cs
// Current app version (2.0.0)
var currentVersion = VersionTracking.CurrentVersion;

// Current build (2)
var currentBuild = VersionTracking.CurrentBuild;
```

Comment: Technically the image he is showing is the Solution version number, not the native app bundle verion/buid...

Comment: @SushiHangover Good point, I missed that. Anyway, using the bundle version or build number might be more beneficial for OP in the long run, would you agree?

Comment: I do agree, but there are people that use the solution version, i have a couple of clients that do ‍♂️, give up on asking "Can you explain why just one more time?...  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455094/4984832

Comment: Thanks for the link! :)